# How to specify values in JSON key

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a JSON and I want to access the keys in `"rates"`. This is the aforementioned JSON:

```py
currency = '''
{
  "rates": {
    "CNY": 7.6588,
    "BGN": 1.9558,
    "USD": 1.114
  },
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2019-07-24"
}
'''

qwe = json.loads(currency)
```

When i try

```py
for x in qwe['rates']:
    print(x)
```

I get the values CNY, BGN, USD without the keys.

But also when I try `print(qwe['rates'])` I get `{'CNY': 7.6588, 'BGN': 1.9558, 'USD': 1.114}`

My idea is to specify the keys for each value

Comment: `I get the values CNY, BGN, USD without the keys.` those ARE the keys. ;) E.g. key is 'CNY', value is '7.6588'. You can do `for key, value in qwe['rates'].items():` to get both key and value at once.

Comment: "I get the values CNY, BGN, USD without the keys." Um, those *are* the keys. But the difference here is that a dictionary iterator only provides the keys, not key/value pairs. `print` treats `qwe['rates']` as a *string*, not an iterator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: Ah my mistake :D But THANKS a lot ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qwe = json.loads(currency)
for key, value in qwe['rates'].items():
    # do something with 'key' here
```

Answer (score 2):

To access the value you have to print qwe['rates'][x]

```
for x in qwe['rates']:
  print(qwe['rates'][x])
```

Output

```
7.6588
1.9558
1.114
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the .items() dict method:

```
for key, value in qwe['rates'].items():
    print(key, value)
```